# Query Params in the react router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I am totally new to the react router.

I have this route

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/quiz-setup/:job" component={QuizSetupMain} />
```

where I set a param as a job. So I do in action like this

```
history.push({
      pathname: '/quiz-setup',
      search: this.props.selectedJdName
    })
```

My **PrivateRoute** ->

```
return hasUserLogIn ?
    (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        path={path}
        component={Component}
      />
    )
    :
    (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: path }
        }}
      />
    )
};
```

But now, it is not matching that route. So How can I do this?

Comment: uhh then just set the pathname to `/quiz-setup/${this.props.selectedJdName}`

Comment: To expand on azium's comment, it appears you're trying to use a URL param (`search`) when you've declared a path param

Comment: Is there any way to get that param ? if user refresh then I want to take that value so, is there any way ? If it is then should I do it in the componentDidMount ?

Comment: Look at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match

Comment: But because of this, another request which I call, in that also this quiz-setup param is getting added , so its giving me now 404 not found

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Did you update from react router 3 to react router 4? or is it your first react router project?

Comment: its my first react router project

Comment: I have just updated my private Route

Comment: @c-chavez is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate what happens when you try `history.push('/quiz-setup/' + this.props.selectedJdName)` or `/quiz-setup/${this.props.selectedJdName}`?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate if I'm not mistaken, your current approach is the old react-router 3 approach. In react-router 4 there is no query string functionality, just params.

Comment: The solution you have added in a comment has worked. But because of that if some another ali is getting called that time itself then that /quiz-setup is better added in the route. For eg  local host :3000/ABC then it  changes to the localhost/quiz-setup/ABC